# Do While continues after return

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working in WordPress here. I have the following function, it is called from outside the function and then calls itself recursively through a do while loop. I need to use a do while here because I need one iteration when the while condition is true.

The function eventually meets the condition in the `if` statement (within the `do...while`), however it continues to iterate the last iteration endlessly even though I have a `return` statement.

```
public function parent_category_has_fiance($cat_id) {

    global $wpdb;
    $terms = $wpdb->get_row("
                        SELECT
                            term_id, 
                            parent 
                        FROM
                            $wpdb->term_taxonomy
                        WHERE 
                            term_id = $cat_id
                            ");

    do {
        $parent_id = $terms->parent;
        $term_id = $terms->term_id;
        // test if a parent category has a rule
        $does_finance_exist = $this->has_finance($term_id);
        if($does_finance_exist == true) {
            echo "Found parent finance";
            return true;            
        }
        $this->parent_category_has_fiance($parent_id);
    } while ((int)$terms->parent > 0);
    return false;
}
```

Could anyone suggest the issue here?

Comment: Seems here is mistake. Assume, that the selected row doesn't have finance and has non-zero parent, this loop recursively calls itself, when it returns back, this loop will continue endless, because it will process the same record... maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add something like this:

```
$parent_id = $terms->parent;
if( !$parent_id ) return False;
```

I don't know the kind of $terms->parent, so you will have to change condition if the returned value is ≠ False on fail.

Without this modify your recursive call is executed also when there is not `$parent_id` for current `$cat_id`.

Otherwise, you can check `$terms` result and - if empty - return `False`.

#### Edit:

It's hard find a solution without known the sigle methods invoked (maybe add [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) tag can help !), but perhaps this simple code modification can resolve your problem:

```
while( (int)$terms->parent > 0 )
{
    (...)
}
```